# How to know what are the model predictions in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

I am using a custom model built using transfer learning with MobileNetV2 for human awareness detection.

I trained the model and it achieved 99% categorical accuracy on the test data.

There are 3 classes i.e.,  0, 5, 10 which represent the awareness levels

My model returns the following predictions on the input image from TensorCamera in React Native but I am confused as to where the prediction actually is in this Tensor object

```
const prediction = model.predict(tensor.reshape([1,224,224,3]));
```

**Prediction output:**

```
Tensor {
  "dataId": Object {},
  "dtype": "float32",
  "id": 160213,
  "isDisposedInternal": false,
  "kept": false,
  "rankType": "2",
  "scopeId": 365032,
  "shape": Array [
    1,
    3,
  ],
  "size": 3,
  "strides": Array [
    3,
  ],
}
```

**Function to handle camera input and make predictions every 3 frames**

```
  const handleCameraStream = imageAsTensors => {
    const verbose = true;
    console.log("Tensor input 1");
    try {
      tf.print(imageAsTensors, verbose);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Tensor 1 not found!");
    }
    const loop = async () => {
      if (loadedModel !== null) {
        if (frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrames === 0) {
          const imageTensor = imageAsTensors.next().value;
          console.log("Tensor input 2");
          tf.print(imageTensor, verbose);
          await getPrediction(imageTensor).catch(e => console.log(e));
        }
      }

      frameCount += 1;
      frameCount = frameCount % makePredictionsEveryNFrames;
      requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    //loop infinitely to constantly make predictions
    loop();
  };
```

**Function to get predictions**

```
  const getPrediction = async tensor => {
    if (!tensor) {
      console.log("Tensor not found!");
      return;
    }
    const model = await loadedModel;
    const prediction = model.predict(tensor.reshape([1, 224, 224, 3]));
    if (!prediction || prediction.length === 0) {
      console.log("No prediction available");
      return;
    }
    console.log(prediction);
    //console.log(`Predictions: ${JSON.stringify(prediction)}`);

    // Only take the predictions with a probability of 30% and greater
    //Stop looping
    cancelAnimationFrame(requestAnimationFrameId);
    //setPredictionFound(true);
    //setModelPrediction(prediction[0].className);
    tensor.dispose();
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use dataSync() to get the predictions

```
    const preds = prediction.dataSync();
    preds.forEach((pred, i) => {
      //console.log(`x: ${i}, pred: ${pred}`);
      if (pred > 0.8) {
        console.log(`x: ${i}, pred: ${pred}`);
        setModelPrediction(prediction: pred, class: i)
      }
```

```
x: 0, pred: 0.9000627994537354
x: 1, pred: 0.023466499522328377
x: 2, pred: 0.0764707624912262
```